# Edit Item in CSV Array - fast-csv node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I am trying to edit a single element in an array built by **fast-csv** in **Node.JS**.

Fast-csv is editing all the columns when a single array index is included, and no array indexes when a 2D array index is used.

The question is, **is it possible to edit a single element from a CSV in javascript?**

Input (input.csv):

```
hello,1,'1',forty-two, 
yellow,brown,red,orange
```

Current output:

```
[ 'hello', '1', 696, 'forty-two', '' ]
[ 'yellow', 'brown', 696, 'orange' ]
```

Target output:

```
[ 'hello', 'julian', 696, 'forty-two', '' ]
[ 'yellow', 'brown', 696, 'orange' ]
```

Logic:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('fast-csv');


fs.createReadStream('./IOinput/input.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', function(data){
        //console.log(data);
        data[0][1] = 'julian';
        data[2] = 696;

        console.log(data);
    })

    .on('end', function(data){
        console.log('Read finished');
    })
```

Dependencies:

```
npm install fast-csv
```

Comment: `data[2] = 696` works so why don't you try `data[1] = 'julian'` instead of `data[0][1]`

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation the `data` event is fired when a record or a row is read in. So what I would do is create an array and push each record onto the array then make the changes at the end. Another way to do it is to keep a counter of what row is being read in and branching accordingly. I personally think the first option is easier. Here's how it could look:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('fast-csv');

var dataArr = [];
fs.createReadStream('./IOinput/input.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', function(data){
        dataArr.push(data); // Add a row
    })

    .on('end', function(){
        dataArr[0][1] = 'julian';
        dataArr[0][2] = 696;
        dataArr[1][2] = 696;
        console.log(dataArr);
        console.log('Read finished');
    })
```